# Eliminating a blank space at the bottom of website

Tags: html, css

There is a large white space at the bottom of the page.

http://www.generationtrudeau.ca/

I've looked at all the typical culprits (`height` and `min-height` of `body` and `html`, `margin` and `padding`, etc.), but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: If you want debugging help, your question has to include the smallest amount of code to reproduce the problem in the question itself (just linking to external code isn't enough). More info on [MCVE].

Comment: It somehow works if you remove the latest-section `<section class="latest">`. I haven't found out why yet

Comment: remove `padding: 0.5rem;` in `.f-dropdown li a {` in theme.scss

Comment: Thanks, @TamilSelvan! You're completely right. I hadn't thought about that, but the dropdown from that earlier div was causing the problem. If you would like to add your comment as an answer, I will select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `padding: 0.5rem;` in `.f-dropdown li a {` in theme.scss

Comment: Thanks! The culprit was a dropdown menu that extended past the bottom of the page, and this fixed the formatting of that menu.

Answer (score 0):

Just add "`min-height: calc(100% - 305px);`" to the `.main-container` and it should work!